# Does RethinkDb support push updates on complex JOIN/Group by type of query

Tags: rethinkdb

My use case:   I have 20-30 tables that need to be store in DB.  User requirement is to have dynamic ability to query data from multiple tables that can be joined and aggregated and pushed to the client.  Is this something that RethinkDB can support.  Also what is the scalability and how many simultaneous queries can it support lets say with 4 table join (each with 100K of rows).

Also I do not see support for RedHat, can I use  other linux distribution version or it will not work ?

Answer (score 0):

RethinkDB currently doesn't support changefeeds on joins.  You can track progress on that feature at https://github.com/rethinkdb/rethinkdb/issues/3997 .  You can get changefeeds on individual tables and do subqueries based on the changes to that table, however (`r.table('test').changes().concatMap(whatever)`).